# Issue with SVG in IE with max-width

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, svg

So I'm not sure if this is a bug or I am just doing something wrong..

When using max-width with an SVG the image becomes distorted in IE 9,10

Example below (must be view in IE of course...)

http://codepen.io/Unroku/pen/nEgza

Answer (score 1):

Set the max-height also.

```
.papa {
  width: 250px;
}

.mama {
  max-width: 250px; 
  max-height: 250px;
}
img {
  vertical-align: top;
}
body {
  padding: 20px; 
}
```

Comment: Yes does not work in IE 10 and below (https://jsfiddle.net/uj0uhkkq/1/)